# Why commands in tcl scripts are not added to the history

Tags: tcl, tclsh

test.tcl

```
puts 1
puts 2
history
puts [history event [expr [history nextid] - 1]]
```

in tclsh

```
% source test.tcl
1
2
source test.tcl
%
```

Why commands in tcl scripts are not added to the history?

How to automatically add commands from scripts to the history？

Comment: If you want to change this behaviour I think you would need to manage it yourself, see https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/history.htm

Comment: From the 'history' man page: _The  history  command  performs  one  of  several operations related to recently-executed commands..._  I think it is implied that the history has to do with what the _user_ types, not every command called by every proc. It's analogous to the command line shell history - it records what _we_ type, not what other commands are run by shell scripts. It sounds like you want logging or tracing... maybe the `trace` command will help with that?

Comment: Logging _every_ command executed by Tcl internally would be incredibly slow. The `history` command is for maintaining a history of things done by the user; the Tcl standard interactive shell uses it, but scripts basically do not.